# Spring MVC vs Spring WebFlow

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I am doing some research for some social network project which i am going to start. I used Spring before yet i cant make a decision at the moment since there are way too many options to choose.

I would like to use JSF2.0  components on my views , and as far as i figure out webflow is a nice way of doing it yet it is not a must.

What benefits does webflow give over Spring web mvc ? My first impression about WF is it makes things way too complicated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The main difference is that people actually use Spring MVC! http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=spring+mvc%2C+spring+webflow%2C+spring+web+flow&l=. I have used Web Flow and had a very difficult time finding documentation and community support for the (many) edge cases when it wasn't flexible enough for my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webflow is about flows in web application.

Think of a Wizzard with several Pages, then Web Flow helps you to connect this Pages (in a flow), and provides a variable scope to connect variable with this flow.

While Spring MVC is "only" about isolated Pages.

Comment: so not everything can be expressed as webflow and its possible to  use SpringWeb flow for Spring Faces and dont bother with flows and such. Since i dont want a wizard like structure ? am i getting this right?

Comment: @imellan: The wizzard was only one example, an other would be for example the order process of amazon. -- In general if you do not have such a multi page flow, you do not need Spring Web Flow, then Spring MVC is enough.